# Ubuntu 16.04 Ran out of space unable to recover

Tags: apt, partitioning, package-management, data-recovery

I have a Web Server and i ran out of space on / as shown below

```
root@6710b:/var/log# df
Filesystem                 1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                         2000304         0   2000304   0% /dev
tmpfs                         403820      5924    397896   2% /run
/dev/mapper/6710b--vg-root 149336372 147265404         0 100% /
tmpfs                        2019088         0   2019088   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        2019088         0   2019088   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                     240972     55853    172678  25% /boot
tmpfs                         403820         0    403820   0% /run/user/1000
```

Things that I've tried:

- `apt-get purge`.
- `apt-get autoremove`.
- I manually deleted old kernels from `/boot` but still it didn't release the space, I am desperate to get this up and running.
- deleted contents of /var/log & /var/cache/apt/archives/ and then rebooted the OS

Please help, i have spent better part of my day googling and trying everything that mentioned in many of the questions on stack exchange but none helped

None of these things are helping me recover space

Many of these commands says unmet dependencies and wants me to run `apt-get -f install`, but that fails because there is no more space left.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of terminal output. Just copy and paste it into your question, select it, and press the `{}` button in the question editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted the contents of /var/tmp

It seems newer version of ubuntu is storing lot of old information here

Answer (score 3):

Read your output carefully:

- Your /boot is only at 25%. It's not full. That's not the problem.
- Your / is at 100%. Completely full. That's the problem.

Deleting packages might help a little, but not much (`sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*`). Sometimes doing that creates other problems ("oops, I needed that!"), so don't nuke your package cache first.

Check your /var/log for runaway log files (1GB or more). Don't simply delete a huge log - read it and figure out the problem. Fix the problem that causes the log to grow.

Otherwise, look for files you can delete or archive to another media. If you encrypt the archive, keep the key you used in a safe, recoverable place. You may not remember it years from now.

Comment: Simply deleting a log is not enough.  You need to restart the process writing to it.  The kernel will hold onto disk space until all open file handles to a log are closed.

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37221/finding-files-that-use-the-most-disk-space